# Excel VBA- how to carry values from one Userform spreadsheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a purchase order spreadsheet and an invoice spreadsheet. Purchase orders are put into the sheet via a UserForm, which then populates the sheet for me. Works great.

Then I have another worksheet for invoices. This information is also put into its spreadsheet via a UserForm.

The common denominator in both is the purchase order number that is given during the first phase.

I would like to find some way, if possible, to hinge my second spreadsheet and UserForm on this purchase order number. This way, data entry doesn't have to re-enter identifying information and only has to add to that of which is already there.

Comment: if i understand it correct you have 1 workbook with 2 worksheets and 2 userforms, you want to use the purchase order number filled in the 1st userform to be put in the 2nd userform that then loads more data into the invoice userform?

Comment: if for example `userform.textbox1` is where you fill in the purchase order number then in userform2 you do this: `userform2.textbox1.value = userform.textbox1.value`

Comment: I have tried this in a few places but cannot get it to work. Do you have a suggestions for where to add this code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you add the code part(s) where you tried to add the code?

Comment: Private Sub txtPO_Change()
frmTest2.txtPO.Value = frmTest.txtpo2.Value
End Sub

Comment: My first userform is "frmTest" and my second is "frmTest2"

Comment: Is at the time the change event occurs the frmtest2 already loaded? If not you cant set anything as the userform isnt loaded

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I am so new to this. Would you suggest adding it in a different part of the code?

Comment: The txtPO_change() is from which userform?

Comment: The first one. frmTest.

Comment: That is where the problem lies i think, unless the frmtest2 is already loaded you cant set any values to anything in the userform

Comment: By loaded do you mean set up? It's already set up, and coded to dump info from the UserForm to its worksheet. They both are working. It's just this PO# once entered hold a lot of other information that also needs dumping on the invoice worksheet, once an invoice is entered.

Comment: By loaded i mean that when frmtest is running that frmtest2 should also be running in order to feed it information from frmtest

Answer (score 1):

This can be done given UserForm1 is still loaded.  Once finished with the UserForm1 sub routine do not close/unload the userform.  Instead use the following code,

```
UserForm1.Hide
```

Then Load UserForm2 and then use the code,

```
UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
Unload UserForm1
```

Some issues may arise if the user is able to edit the sheet before starting UserForm2, but if the User starts UserForm2 immediately after finishing UserForm1 this should work.